# ¿Cómo emitir string con SocketIO por segundo en html con Python3 y Flask?

Tags: javascript, html, python, flask, socket.io

Estoy usando SocketIO con Flask en Python3 y no puedo refrescar un tag 'div' en el html con JavaScript. Solo quiero que el trabajo lo haga el servidor. Éste es parte del código:

Python3:

```
@app.route("/chat", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def in_game():
    room = session.get('room', '')
    game_on = True
    user = User.get_by_id(current_user.id)
    player = Player.get_by_id(current_user.id)
    game = Game.get_by_id(current_user.id)
    tiempo_partida = datetime.now()
    while game_on:
        socketio.emit('game', {'info': "State: "+game.state+" Time: "+(tiempo_partida - datetime.now()).__str__()[14:19]+" Piece: "+player.piece+" Position: "+player.pos}, namespace='/chat')
        return render_template("game2.html", room=room)
```

html:

```
{% extends "base_template.html" %}
{% block title %}client{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
  var socket;
  $(document).ready(function(){
    socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/chat');
    socket.on('game', function(data) {
      $('#state').val($('#state').val() = data.info);
    });
  });
</script>
<body>
  <div id="state"></div><br><br>
</body>
```

El código no me da error pero no actualiza el string que quiero.

Comment: ¿por que no implementas un timer del lado de js que pida la información cada T segundos?

Comment: Es lo que estoy haciendo por el momento, porque parece lo más lógico. Pero me gustaria una respuesta a la pregunta.